# Calculating dps - damage of abilities

Tags: the-secret-world

- How is the damage on abilities calculated?
- Is there a resource that shows the formulas for all the abilities
  in game?
- Is there a good way to calculate the dps of a specific deck?

I like to find the best (most DPS) deck for my current weapons, so I would like to do some theoriecrafting instead of trying out and testing the DPS. Its mainly because the DPS meters available right now are not really satisfying for me and I would like to have a better idea how my combat stats effect my DPS with a specific deck of abilities.

It is extremely useful for me to know my DPS so I can calculate how long it will take me to kill an enemy, because I'm fairly new to the game and I don't have much experience on how challenging encounters are.